# Installing Flash 11.4 on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, software-installation, adobe-flash

Is it possible to install Adobe Flash 11.4 on Fedora 21?  I have been reading that Flash 11.2 is the only option.  Help!

Comment: I understand that many things still use flash, but the current recommended trend is to NOT use it anymore. Adobe themselves are trying to get people to stop using it. http://www.theverge.com/2015/12/1/9827778/stop-using-flash I would suggest you first make sure you absolutely need it https://linuxconfig.org/fedora-linux-firefox-blocks-outdated-adobe-flash-solution

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Fedora 21 (I don't have any F21 systems anymore, since it's end-of-lifed — time to upgrade!) but I tried the [just-released August 2016 beta version of Flash 23](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/08/beta-news-flash-player-npapi-for-linux.html), and it appears to work.

Note, though, the caveat at the end and in the comments — apparently there are some kinks that haven't been worked out and some sites may cause crashes. I think it's *best* to avoid Flash altogether, but sometimes, you just can't. For those cases, I'd suggest keeping Google Chrome on hand, because it includes a built-in and up-to-date version which works fine on Fedora.